# Some commits are on two branches. Why?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have two branches: Voip and Elastic.
In some commits are showing "2 branches". Why this happens?

[image: My Commits]

Comment: Is this only the case before you seperated your branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that 2 branches "have" this commit, or to rephrase it in git terms, that this commit is [*reachable*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefreachableareachable) through 2 branches.

Nothing unusual or problematic per se.

Example :

```
A---B---C <<< branch1
     \
      D---E <<< branch2
```

Here, both `A` and `B` would feature the same "2 branches" mention.

(You could, for the sake of the experiment, create a new branch at `B`, and then observe the mention "3 branches" on `A` and `B`.)

Comment: There is a way to rollback it? Or remove this commits from just only one branch?

Comment: I'm not sure about exactly *what* you want to rollback. If the situation is the result of an unwanted merge, it can be reverted, or if you're alone on the branch, its history can be rewritten, there are solutions, but we know far too few about your situation to safely advise anything. Could you describe the problem you're facing? (other than this "2 branches" mention which unsettled you)

Answer (score 2):

This happens typically when changes have been merged from a branch into another.

The commits will appear on both the branches,So if you had ever:

1. merged `voip` into `elastic`
2. Created `voip` from `elastic`

Or similar situations.

And like RomainValeri has mentioned it is nothing to worry about. In fact it gives  a way to trace back commit, via the path.